# Search form in Flask only works from some pages

Tags: python, flask

I have a search form in the base template so that the user can search from any page. If they search from `/`, `/home`, or `/speciesinfo`, it works correctly.  If they search from the search results page, `/speciesinfo/<nrcs_species>`, it does not work. Why does my search only work from some pages?

```
@app.route('/result', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        spp = request.form.get('query')
        query = SPInfo.query

        if spp:
             query = query.filter(or_(
                 (func.lower(SPInfo.NRCS_Species.contains(spp))),
                 (func.lower(SPInfo.NRCS_CommonName.contains(spp))),
                 (func.lower(SPInfo.MTNHP_Species.contains(spp))),
                 (func.lower(SPInfo.Synonyms.contains(spp))),
             ))

        return render_template('result.html', results=query.all())

    return render_template('result.html')
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="result">
    <input name="query"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `form` definition in your `layout.html` file to:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('result') }}">
```

And it should fix your problem.